# slice based on a masked tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

This is my reproducible code:

```
tf_ent = tf.Variable([   [9.96,    8.65,    0.99,    0.1 ],
                         [0.7,     8.33,    0.1  ,   0.1   ],
                         [0.9,     0.1,     6,       7.33],
                         [6.60,    0.1,     3,       5.5 ],
                         [9.49,    0.2,     0.2,     0.2   ],
                         [0.4,     8.45,    0.2,     0.2 ],
                         [0.3,     0.2,     5.82,    8.28]])

tf_ent_var = tf.constant([True, False, False, False, False, True, False])
```

I want to keep the rows in `tf_ent` in which the correspondent indices in  `tf_ent_var` is True and make the rest of the rows to minimum in the whole matrice.

so the expected output would be like this:

```
                    [[9.96,    8.65,    0.99,   0.1 ],
                     [0.1,     0.1,     0.1  ,  0.1 ],
                     [0.1,     0.1,     0.1,    0.1 ],
                     [0.1,     0.1,     0.1,    0.1 ],
                     [0.1,     0.1,     0.1,    0.1 ],
                     [0.4,     8.45,    0.2,      0.2 ],
                     [0.1,     0.1,     0.1,    0.1 ]]
```

Any idea how can I do that?

I tried to get indices out of the masked tensor and then using the tf.gather to accomplish this one, but the indices I get were like this `[[0], [6]]` which makes sense because it gave the index of one vector.

Comment: How is the "minimum in the whole matrice" 0.1 when 0 exists in both the rows you want and the rows you don't want?

Comment: @ImperishableNight, I had to make the matrice smaller and forgot to replace zeros:|, I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: For tensorflow 1.x, use:

```
val = tf.math.reduce_min(tf_ent)
tf.where(tf_ent_var, tf_ent, tf.zeros_like(tf_ent) + val)
```

Unfortunately, the broadcast rules are not a subset of the 2.0 rules (which is the same as numpy), but are "just different". Tensorflow is not the best library when it comes to version compatibility.

---

The basic idea is to use `tf.where`, but you will need to first change `tf_ent_var` into a tensor with shape `(7, 1)`, so that tensorflow knows to broadcast it in the second axis instead of in the first axis. So:

```
val = tf.math.reduce_min(tf_ent)
tf.where(tf_ent_var[:, tf.newaxis], tf_ent, val)
```

Of course you can also reshape it into `(-1, 1)`, but I think slicing with `tf.newaxis` is shorter and clearer.

---

Here is my Python interactive session with 1.13.1, for troubleshooting purpose.

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
2019-06-22 15:51:09.210852: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>>> tf_ent = tf.Variable([   [9.96,    8.65,    0.99,    0.1 ],
...                          [0.7,     8.33,    0.1  ,   0.1   ],
...                          [0.9,     0.1,     6,       7.33],
...                          [6.60,    0.1,     3,       5.5 ],
...                          [9.49,    0.2,     0.2,     0.2   ],
...                          [0.4,     8.45,    0.2,     0.2 ],
...                          [0.3,     0.2,     5.82,    8.28]])
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/REDACTED/Documents/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
>>> 
>>> tf_ent_var = tf.constant([True, False, False, False, False, True, False])
>>> init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
>>> sess.run(init)
>>> val = tf.math.reduce_min(tf_ent)
>>> tf.where(tf_ent_var, tf_ent, tf.zeros_like(tf_ent) + val)
<tf.Tensor 'Select:0' shape=(7, 4) dtype=float32>
>>> _.eval()
array([[9.96, 8.65, 0.99, 0.1 ],
       [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ],
       [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ],
       [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ],
       [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ],
       [0.4 , 8.45, 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ]], dtype=float32)
>>> tf.__version__
'1.13.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I got this error 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Inputs to operation Select of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [7,1] != input 1: [7,4] [Op:Select]
'

Comment: Oh, I'm using tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 (and tensorflow made sure that I know this, because every error it throws is from a function named `something_v2`, like `where_v2` and `select_v2`). In tensorflow 1.x `where` is probably not this flexible. I will try looking for a solution in 1.x.

Comment: Im not sure should I update to beta version, please let me know if you find any approach working with tf.13

Comment: the `val` value will not be added to tf.zeros tensor, so the output do not have 0.1 in the final matrice

Comment: I tried to update it, but it sounds it related to tensorflow version, did you get exactly the same output I shared in the question?

Comment: Huh? When I tested it worked all right. Are you sure you didn't mis-copy anything? My tensorflow version for this is 1.13.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
min_mat = tf.broadcast_to(tf.reduce_min(tf_ent), tf_ent.shape)
output = tf.where(tf_ent_var, tf_ent, min_mat)
sess.run(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation using `tf.concat()` and `if-else` statement. It's not as elegant as other's answer, but is working:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def slice_tensor_based_on_mask(tf_ent, tf_ent_var):
    res = tf.fill([1, 4], 0.0)  
    min_value_tensor = tf.fill([1,int(tf_ent.shape[1])], tf.reduce_min(tf_ent))

    for i in range(int(tf_ent.shape[0])):
        if tf_ent_var[i:i+1].numpy()[0]: # true value in tf_ent_var
            res = tf.concat([res, tf_ent[i:i+1]], 0)
        else:
            res = tf.concat([res, min_value_tensor], 0)
    return res[1:]

tf_ent = tf.Variable([[9.96,    8.65,    0.99,   0.1 ],
                     [0.7,     8.33,    0.1  ,   0.1 ],
                     [0.9,     0.1,     6,       7.33],
                     [6.60,    0.1,     3,       5.5 ],
                     [9.49,    0.2,     0.2,     0.2 ],
                     [0.4,     8.45,    0.2,     0.2 ],
                     [0.3,     0.2,     5.82,    8.28]])

tf_ent_var = tf.constant([True, False, False, False, False, True, False])
print(slice_tensor_based_on_mask(tf_ent, tf_ent_var))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[9.96 8.65 0.99 0.1 ]
 [0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ]
 [0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ]
 [0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ]
 [0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ]
 [0.4  8.45 0.2  0.2 ]
 [0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 ]], shape=(7, 4), dtype=float32)
```